# Are the php-zts extensions needed when the mpm is event?

Tags: apache-2.4, php5, mpm-worker

my php is correctly installed and working, but at Apache startup I have all the current loaded extensions with warning messages like...

```
[23-Dec-2015 21:47:45 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: bz2: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with build ID=API20131226,NTS
PHP    compiled with build ID=API20131226,TS
These options need to match
 in Unknown on line 0
[23-Dec-2015 21:47:45 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: calendar: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with build ID=API20131226,NTS
PHP    compiled with build ID=API20131226,TS
These options need to match
 in Unknown on line 0
[23-Dec-2015 21:47:45 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: ctype: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with build ID=API20131226,NTS
PHP    compiled with build ID=API20131226,TS
These options need to match
 in Unknown on line 0
[23-Dec-2015 21:47:45 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/modules/curl.so' - /usr/lib64/php/modules/curl.so: undefined symbol: compiler_globals in Unknown on line 0
[23-Dec-2015 21:47:45 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/modules/dom.so' - /usr/lib64/php/modules/dom.so: undefined symbol: executor_globals in Unknown on line 0
[23-Dec-2015 21:47:45 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/modules/exif.so' - /usr/lib64/php/modules/exif.so: undefined symbol: compiler_globals in Unknown on line 0
[23-Dec-2015 21:47:45 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/modules/fileinfo.so' - /usr/lib64/php/modules/fileinfo.so: undefined symbol: file_globals in Unknown on line 0
[23-Dec-2015 21:47:45 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: ftp: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with build ID=API20131226,NTS
PHP    compiled with build ID=API20131226,TS
These options need to match
 in Unknown on line 0
```

and so on...

as you can see the current extension dir is set to **/usr/lib64/php/modules**

but as I know the php for mpm event is loaded into the php.conf with
...

**LoadModule php5_module modules/libphp5-zts.so**

so, the question is...
Do I need to load the extensions from /usr/lib64/***php-zts***/modules ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The answer is no, but found the issue.

With mpm event + fcgid obviously any virtual host has its php.ini in ../home/user/etc/php5
so before the main /etc/php.ini (when prefork...) was manually set to /usr/lib64/php/modules and wasn't good to do testing editing the /etc/php.ini.

Had to edit any php.ini for users and comment out the extension_dir line...
no more warning messages about the extensions.